# Execute immediate with variable throwing error ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Getting missing expression error when my procedure reaches this statement. 
ORA-00936: missing expression
What is wrong with this statement?

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT /*+ parallel (8) */ COUNT(1)
  INTO '||v_datacount_backuptable||
  ' FROM cs_transassignment_26weeks';
```

Comment: What is `v_datacount_backuptable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT /*+ parallel (8) */ COUNT(1) FROM cs_transassignment_26weeks'
  INTO v_datacount_backuptable;
```

i.e. `INTO` is outside of the statement being executed.

Comment: This was faster than me although maybe less comprehensive... +1 anyway.

Comment: Actually this statement is inside a package with 11 procedures. Table cs_transassignment_26weeks is just a temp table created with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create table as. That table gets used in few statements. We have written all of those statements as dynamic SQL coz:   This table is dropped at the end of the procedure as it is of no use and saves space. However when I run next procedure , the package goes uncompiled if I write it as simple SELECT COINT(1) INTO v_datacount_backuptable FROM cs_transassignment_26weeks . So dynamic SQL

Comment: That sounds wrong. In my opinion, you should create table only once and use it any time you want. Two options: use a global temporary table (its contents will be lost at the end of transaction or session, depending on how you create it) or - if it is a "normal" table - truncate it once your job is done.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve is unclear. In any case, you cannot pass a variable name *as a variable*.

If you want to feed the count into the variable from a fixed query, then you can skip the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`: it is meant to execute a query that is dynamically composed, which is not the case in the code that you showed:

```
declare v_datacount_backuptable int;
begin
  SELECT /*+ parallel (8) */ COUNT(1) INTO v_datacount_backuptable FROM cs_transassignment_26weeks;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_datacount_backuptable);
end;
/
```

If you actually built the query somewhere else and you need to execute it, then, as answered by Littlefoot already, you need to move the `INTO` clause out of the query string:

```
declare 
    v_datacount_backuptable int;
    v_query varchar(500);
begin
  v_query := 'SELECT /*+ parallel (8) */ COUNT(1) FROM cs_transassignment_26weeks';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query INTO v_datacount_backuptable;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_datacount_backuptable);
end;
/
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60da680177394166b29d0124c5789950)**

Comment: Thank you. v_datacount_backuptable is a variable with NUMBER datatype. As this was an extract of a big procedure, I missed out to copy the declarations.